# SSRS borders less than 1pt thick

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a tablix with cells that have only their bottom borders turned on. I've been able to get the borders to be 1pt thick, but I would like to make them .5pt or less. Visual studio let's me change it in the gui, but when I go back into it it is back to 1pt. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: You need to remember that SSRS uses an CSS engine from 1999 and I doubt it will recognise partial sizes on borders.

Think "css for email"

Comment: I usually use .5pt borders (when I still use them - I mostly use alternate row color now) and never noticed a problem with them. I don't see why it only being the bottom border would make a difference. Can you make other changes to the report that don't revert back?